# Work done in close loop by conservative force

Tags: energy, work

Why is work done by a conservative force in a closed loop zero?  My teacher said that velocity at the starting point of the loop will be equal when we arrive after completing the loop.  Hence, kinetic energy will be zero but I am not sure about it...can you tell me the reason

Comment: @XcoderX how does conservation of energy prove this

Comment: I have provided a brief explanation, please reply what you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force, a conservative force is a force with the property that the total work done in moving a particle between two points is independent of the taken path.  This would mean that if the object travels in a closed loop, it will have zero work done, since work done is equal to force multiplied by distance, and that distance is zero.  Conservative force is also such that is conserves energy.

Comment: This surely helps....so it doesn't have anything to do with velocity?

Comment: Yes, @GENESECT.  It is the force at play here.  Why do you think it would have anything to velocity?

Comment: It's just my teacher said that the kinetic energy will be conserved and hence work done is zero....but looking from your explanation can't we infer that velocity will be conserved?

Comment: You cannot conserve velocity, but yes, kinetic energy is conserved here

Comment: Okay.Thanx for the help

Comment: One more doubt.For non conservative forces,the relation work done=force x distance won't work as energy is not conserved and so we can't say the same for it

Comment: Yes, that is where friction  comes into play.